# Workflow getting suspended after selecting Task outcome :Sharepoint designer Workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, designer-workflow

Issue I am facing,

1. Sharepoint designer List workflow
2. Assign Task , OutCome => custom content type with three options.
3. If statement if outcome=="someting" => go to next stage (here it is getting suspended)
   [image]

[image]

Any idea where it is throwing null ref error?

Comment: I have done bit research and came to conclusion that always return the outcome:0, means default value of outcome get return. inspite of selected any other outcome, it returns the default one. any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging into it came to know issue was this:
[workflow custom outcome choice site column takes always default value](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67939/workflow-custom-outcome-choice-site-column-takes-always-default-value)

Its SharePoint bug,I have resolved it by doing trick which I have explained in my blog:

http://anujabhojani.blogspot.in/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-workflow-error-custom.html

Answer (score 0):

Inadequate App Step permissions is usually the source of this error.  I solved it by enabling an App Step Feature, and granting permissions to the App Step.  For detailed steps, please see: http://www.reality-tech.com/workflow-error-in-sp2013-related-to-app-step/

Comment: Please don't add the exact same answer to this question, as you did on [this one](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149888/sharepoint-workflow-2013-always-suspended/175725#175725). Instead, try to specify your answer further to make it a better of this specific question. Thank You!