# workflow custom outcome choice site column takes always default value

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, 2013

I am facing a weird issue,

Having one programmatically created Workflow custom task list , Content type and Custom outcome site column.

Task outcome always return the taskOutcome: 0 (i.e default one)

I have tried by creating task outcome column manually which returns the result as per the expectation.

Compared the schema of both the outcome columns(one manual,second code through create)
both are same.

```
<Field Type="OutcomeChoice" DisplayName="test outcome1" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Group="GIMS Workflows Site Columns" ID="{c3ff4b5d-c283-4e53-a1ae-61d90a6d84ae}" SourceID="{08fc57b6-0135-4ab1-b698-9de05eebe641}" StaticName="test_x0020_outcome1" Name="test_x0020_outcome1" FillInChoice="FALSE" Version="1">
<Default>Action Implemented</Default>
<CHOICES>
  <CHOICE>Action Implemented</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>Revise Action Plan</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>Abort</CHOICE>
</CHOICES>
```

```
  <Field ID="{8250e1c8-8d7f-44bb-b736-929f598756d4}" DisplayName="Implement Actions Task Outcome" Name="GIMS_ActionImplementedTaskOutcomes" Type="OutcomeChoice" Sealed="FALSE" Group="GIMS Workflows Site Columns" Description="Custom GIMS Action Implemented IP Outcome" SourceID="{08fc57b6-0135-4ab1-b698-9de05eebe641}" StaticName="GIMS_ActionImplementedTaskOutcomes" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" FillInChoice="FALSE" Version="1">
<Default>Actions Implemented</Default>
<CHOICES>
  <CHOICE>Actions Implemented</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>Revise Action Plan</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>Aborted</CHOICE>
</CHOICES>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its SharePoint bug,I have resolved it by doing trick which I have explained in my blog:

http://anujabhojani.blogspot.in/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-workflow-error-custom.html