# SharePoint Workflow 2013 Always Suspended

Tags: 2013, workflow, workflow-manager

We are having this issue in **SP Workflow 2013** that even we create a simple workflow like sending email or just changing status name it always goes to Suspended stage.

Below is the error we always experience:

[image]

> RequestorId: 1236f263-86b3-1728-0000-000000000000. Details: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow
>   instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 401
>   {"error_description":"The server was unable to process the request due
>   to an internal error. For more information about the error, either
>   turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from
>   ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration
>   behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information
>   back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET
>   Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs."}
>   {"x-ms-diagnostics":["3001000;reason=\"There has been an error
>   authenticating the
>   request.\";category=\"invalid_client\""],"SPRequestGuid":["1236f263-86b3-1728-b863-e8c83aefd80d"],"request-id":["1236f263-86b3-1728-b863-e8c83aefd80d"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"SPRequestDuration":["42"],"SPIisLatency":["1"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.5"],"WWW-Authenticate":["Bearer
>   realm=\"9445b918-6209-4438-900e-2e406a825b5f\",client_id=\"00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000\",trusted_issuers=\"00000005-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*,00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000@9445b918-6209-4438-900e-2e406a825b5f\"","NTLM"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4641"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1;
>   RequireReadOnly"],"Date":["Wed, 22 Jul 2015 02:30:12 GMT"]} at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine`1.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

We already configured SMTP Mail, User Profile Service in our server but we still cant still make SP Worflow 2013 work.

Other thing that I noticed, the modified by in 2013 is using domain/username but in 2010 its using UserName [DomainGroup].

Comment: Is this a Designer or Visual Studio workflow? Do all actions fail (write to history, update list item, query web service) or just specific ones (email)?

Comment: We only use SharePoint Designer. All the actions failed, the workflow started but it goes to suspended.

Comment: Is it sharepoint online or on prem?

Comment: I had once a problem with my memory (over 90% were used) and also don't try the workflow as a systemaccount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after weeks of struggling here I found the solution.

I just need to activate Workflow can use app permissions in Site Settings and create elevated permission.

I followed this link: [Create a workflow with elevated permissions by using the SharePoint 2013 Workflow platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx)
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

While creating the 2013 workflow go the workflow settings and uncheck the "Automatically update the workflow status to the current status" checkbox.

In the workflow, just write a log to history list and try to publish.
Check if the workflow is working.

Answer (score 0):

Inadequate App Step permissions is usually the source of this error.  I solved it by enabling an App Step Feature, and granting permissions to the App Step.  For detailed steps, please see: http://www.reality-tech.com/workflow-error-in-sp2013-related-to-app-step/

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 401 error (Unauthorized) resulting in workflow Suspended internal status also occurs when the initiator of the workflow no longer has access to the list item (or other items to be updated by the workflow).

For example, consider a user who creates a list item, initiating a workflow that creates a task for someone else. If the initiator leaves the enterprise and is removed from active directory, when the task is completed, this same HTTP 401 result happens if the workflow then tries to update the workflow status for that list item.